# Passing an String array to a Prepared Statement Array (JDBC + SQLServer)

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to pass an String array to a prepared statement, but it's returning this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: This operation is not supported.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.createArrayOf(SQLServerConnection.java:2763)
    at entity.dao.getRecords(Dao.java:168)
    at entity.dao.main(Dao.java:227)
```

my code is:

```
public List<Record> getRecords() throws SQLException {
        String sql = "select * from table where clause in (?)";

        PreparedStatement ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("string1");
        strings.add("string2");
        strings.add("string3");

        Array array = this.connection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", strings.toArray());

        ps.setArray(1, array);

        ResultSet executeQuery = ps.executeQuery();
        List<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();
        Record record;
        while (executeQuery.next()) {
            // ...
        }
        return records;
    }
```

the line of the exception is `Array array = this.connection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", strings.toArray());`

it's when i try to create the Array.

I already searched how to pass the Array and everybody tells to do like this, but seems to don't work with SQLServer.

Comment: Use this: `ps.setString(1,"'comma', 'separated', 'values'");`

Comment: this example is only didatic. at the scenario that i'm working, i have a hundred of strings.

Comment: @GordThompson this post don't talk about sql-server.

Comment: *"this post don't talk about sql-server"* - but it does talk about using plain JDBC, which is what you are apparently trying to do. The principle is the same.

Comment: According to the stack trace, seems like the SQL Server JDBC driver doesn't support the `createArrayOf()` method.

Comment: The source code for the driver is on GitHub.  If you look at the stack trace, this function is, indeed, not implemented and just throws the exception in your question.

Comment: Ya, i know. The featured wasn't implemented. I already know this. I'm only searching some solution, pass an array in a "where in clause"

Answer (score 1):

you can use, Alternatively, a createQuery statemen (Entity Manager)

```
String sql= "select * from Table table where table.clause IN :clauses"; 
Query query = em.createQuery(sql, Record.class);

List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("string1");
        strings.add("string2");
        strings.add("string3");

query.setParameter("clauses", strings );
List<Record> result= query .getResultList();
```

Comment: this is a solution, but i'm having troubles with JPA that i don't know how to resolve.

Comment: when i insert the annotations, @Entity @Table(name="table"), in my Entity Class, the entityManager don't works anymore.

Comment: can you print the error

Comment: `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: usuarios] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory ........
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: entity.record ...........`

Comment: you msut specify the id of the entity using:
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

Comment: i did this: `@Column(name="id") @ID private long id;`, didn't work too

Comment: make sure that you are using import javax.persistence.Id; for the @ID importation

Comment: Ya, exactly from javax.persistence